# android bitmap translation animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm developing a backgammon game.I draw board and pieces using canvas.drawBitmap. I wanna move the pieces from one location to another using animation. how can I do that? I think I should do some kind of translation animation. Can I do that with bitmaps?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code for animating ImageView:

```
final ImageView btnTranslate1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.translate1);
Animation translateAnimation1 = new TranslateAnimation(0f, x, 0f, y);
translateAnimation1.setDuration(500);
translateAnimation1.setInterpolator(new CircInterpolator(Type.INOUT));

// start your animation with this line
btnTranslate1.startAnimation(translate1);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I'm not using imageviews. as I told in the question I directly draw bitmaps on canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Create global position coordinates for your pieces and update them using [Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html).

```
Point positionOfPiece;

private static final int FINAL_X = 5;
private static final int FINAL_Y = 5;

private static final int INITIAL_X = 5;
private static final int INITIAL_Y = 5;

private class CustomAnimation extends Animation {

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
                Transformation t) {
            createLog("Updating");

            if (interpolatedTime == 0) {
                    positionOfPiece.set(INITIAL_X, INITIAL_Y);
            } else if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                    positionOfPiece.set(FINAL_X, FINAL_Y); 
            } else {
                    positionOfPiece.set((1-interpolatedTime)*INITIAL_X + interpolatedTime*FINAL_X, (1-interpolatedTime)*INITIAL_Y + interpolatedTime*FINAL_Y);
            }
            postInvalidate();
            super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        }

    }
```

Here interpolated time will vary from 0 to 1 (*not precisely depends on interpolator).

according to your duration and interpolator of animation.

```
mAnimation = new CustomAnimation();
mAnimation.setDuration(mDuration);
mAnimation.setInterpolator(mInterpolator);
startAnimation(mAnimation);
```

Comment: thanks. I'll try it, but really bitmaps cannot be animated simpler?

Comment: there is no way to animate any element inside a view except start a continuous process and update its property in it. (But you can animate views using property animator).